# Xamarin.ios and Realm issue with creating realm object

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, realm

Having an issue with my first time using Realm on the Xamarin.ios platform. I am following this tutorial: [Realm and Xamarin Tutorial](https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/14/xamarin-ios-with-realm-mobile-database/)

The issue im having is that when I try to create my object using realm.CreateObject(). I get an error saying "The non-generic method 'Realm.CreateObject(string, object)' cannot be used with type arguments"

Im at a dead end and do not know what to do from here. I have followed the tutorial exactly but still does not work at this point.

ViewController code:

```
private void AddNewCar()
    {
        var realm = Realm.GetInstance();

        realm.Write(() =>
        {
            var newCar = realm.CreateObject<Car>(); //This is where it has an error

        });


    }
```

and this is my public class in another class file:

```
using System;
using Realms;

namespace RealmApp.Model
{
    public class Car: RealmObject
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }

        public Car()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can help!
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your realm.CreateObject to this.
realm.Add(new Car { Brand = "Your Brand", Model = "Your model" });

You can also create the model outside of Add, and just do realm.Add(yourModel)